# Swift Apple Pay/Stripe Features

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, payment, applepay

I was just wondering if it was possible to make 'direct' payments in swift (Stripe/Apple Pay), from 1 person to another, where the owner get's a specific percentage of the total, as a markup for the service? pretty much like how Fiverr works, etc.

Would I have to store all of the card information encrypted & salted server-side, or what are the safest options then?

And also, where can I find a tutorial that shows you exactly how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a read of Stripes documentation before posting.

However it would sound like you want to use Stripe Connect, which would allow you to build a "market place" type solution you are describing.

Note their are a few different ways to implement stripe connect - and you should read up / contact their support before deciding on the best way forward.